# CodeIgniter controller gives 404 or it can't load the view file

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following issue with a simple controller in a CodeIgniter install.

In `controllers/pages.php` the Pages.php controller looks at the URL segments and load static files from folder and sub-folders inside the `/views/pages` directory.

Example:

- If I have `site.com/buy`, then it would load buy.php form `/views/pages`
- If the URL is `site.com/buy/go`, then it would load `go.php` from
  `/views/pages/buy`, while `site.com/buy` would now be `index.php` from
  `/views/pages/buy`

It was changed to add another sub-folder (e.g. `site.com/buy/go/why` from `/views/pages/buy/go/why`);

The controller:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->view(); 
}

private function view() {

    $url_string = $this->uri->uri_string();

    if (!file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/pages/'. $url_string. '/index.php')) {
        if (!file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/pages/' . $url_string . '.php')) {
            show_404();
        } else {
            $path = $url_string . '.php';
        }
    } else {
        $path = $url_string . '/index.php';   
    }

    $this->load->view('pages/' . $path);

}
```

The issue is that I get a 404 regardless of URL.

If I remove `pages/` from `$this->load->view` it would throw another error: unable to load the file; but it does get the file right. (e.g. unable to load `buy/go.php, while the URL is`site.com/buy/go`).

Comment: are you sure that the uri_string() is working correctly? It will return everything after index.php

Comment: I'm not sure; I don't know how to check that since I get 404 regardless of URL. Any suggestion on how to check it? Thanks.

Comment: Well, on PHP you can use var_dump(), try using it on your constructor, just do `var_dump($this->uri->uri_string()); exit();`, just to make sure it is returning what you need.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that it does return the segments (e.g. URL is `site.com/buy/go` and I get `string(9) "buy/go"` and so on).

Comment: In your view method, comment everything and just do this to check `var_dump(APPPATH . 'views/pages/'.$url_string.'/index.php/')` and also `var_dump(APPPATH . 'views/pages/'.$url_string.'.php/');` just to check if the string is ok

Comment: 1st works ok if URL has 1 segment (e.g. `site.com/buy/go` would output `/views/pages/buy/go/index.php`, but it should be `/views/pages/buy/go.php`; `site.com/buy` would output `/views/pages/buy/index.php` which is ok). 2nd is the 1st reversed, it seems.

Comment: No, the same error regardless of what I do and/or try.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been playing around trying a few different things out to see what was going on.

I won't go into massive detail about everything I tried, but essentially there're only a couple things to change. Using the `__construct()` doesn't appear to work in the way you're trying to use it (ie simply passing all requests to one method). Instead, you'd need to either manually specify all the methods or use routes - so that's what I've done.

Adding the following line to your `config/routes.php` will redirect all requests to the view method:

```
$route['pages/(:any)'] = 'pages/view';
```

Once you've got the route in place there's no need for the `__construct`. The only thing left is to remove the `pages/` part of the path, which you may have already done. I've tested the following code as far down as `/pages/buy/go/test` (3 levels), but in theory it should work the same at any nesting level.

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view()
    {
        $url_string = $this->uri->uri_string();

        if (!file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/'. $url_string. '/index.php'))
        {
            if (!file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/' . $url_string . '.php'))
            {
                show_404();
            }
            else
            {
                $path = $url_string . '.php';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $path = $url_string . '/index.php';   
        }
        $this->load->view($path);
    }
}
```

As a sidenote, you don't need to add the file extension when loading views unless it's something other than `.php`, though it doesn't matter either way.